# why does the pandas module method df.to_csv shows permission error

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I was using the pandas module in python and while trying to change the DataFrame object to csv file by the method `df.to_csv` it showed a permission error. Can anyone recognize the reason and could you show me how to solve this?

Comment: Do you currently have the `csv` open in excel or some other program? That prevents `pandas` from writing to that file, so close it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your program as an administrator. Make sure also that there is no file open with that has the same name. Check as well that the path and filename are correct like the following:

```
final_df.to_csv('D:\Study\Data Science\data sets\MNIST\sample.csv')
```